# How to assign options to a subscript by looping through a TSV?

Tags: bash

I have a TSV file with 3 columns, that is assigned to paramfile.
Here is my script:

```
#! /bin/bash -l

paramfile=/path/to/file

while 
    sample=`sed -n ${number}p $paramfile | awk '{print $1}'`
    Reads1=`sed -n ${number}p $paramfile | awk '{print $2}'`
    Reads2=`sed -n ${number}p $paramfile | awk '{print $3}'`
do
./program.sh $sample $reads1 $reads2
done
```

I want it to read the TSV line by line, and for each line take the content of each column and insert it into my program, to be used as an option in program.sh

I know I haven't got the loop qutie right, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi Biffen, thanks, yes sorry I tihnk I was over complicating the tsv part. Your code looks good. Would it loop trough the tsv line by line, and excute program.sh  once per line?

Comment: Yes. I assumed from your (somewhat cryptic) code that that’s what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` with a ‘custom’ `$IFS` can read TSV<sup>*</sup> into variables, e.g:

```
#!/bin/bash

paramfile=/path/to/file

while IFS="$(printf '\t')" read -r sample reads1 reads2 _
do
  ./program.sh "${sample}" "${reads1}" "${reads2}"
done < "${paramfile}"
```

The `_` is for dropping any trailing cells.

And I took the liberty to quote all variables, as one should.

---

<sup>*Not quoted TSV, though.</sup>

Comment: @Inian Yeah, I thought about that but figured I’d leave it simple, albeit less efficient.